# Black border between two UITableView cells/sections

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I'm trying to figure out how I would go about achieving the visual effect in the screenshot below.

[image]

The black line between Options 2 and 3 is the part I'm struggling with. Would this require two tables? Or is there a way to do this using section headers?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it would be with different sections in the UITableView and the section headers between them.  You have the ability to resize the space between the sections, so you could set it to the height you need.  As for the background, there are lots of different ways to get the black line itself (backing image, custom drawn background for the UIView, etc.)

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely follow. In that solution would I need to be using `UITableViewStyleGrouped` or `UITableViewStylePlain`?

Comment: Grouped.  Although, you could conceivably accomplish the same thing with Plain, but that would require you to do more work to your custom UITableViewCell's to achieve that look.